# How do you execute python code in a website

Tags: python, html

I am creating a website and want to integrate some python code which will be executed and return some information. Here is the code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def trade_spider(max_pages):
    page = 1
    while(page <= max_pages):
            search = 'Ipad'
            url = 'https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_nkw=' + search + '&_sacat=0&_pgn=' + str(page)
            src = requests.get(url)
            text = src.text
            soup = BeautifulSoup(text, features="html.parser")
            for link in soup.findAll('a', {'class': 's-item__link'}):
                    href = link.get('href')
                    title = link.string
                    print(href)
                    if(title == None):
                        title = "Sorry the title was unavailable however you can check the price."
                    print(title)
                    price = get_item_price(href)
                    print(price + '\n')
            page += 1


def get_item_price(item_url):
    src = requests.get(item_url)
    text = src.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(text, features="html.parser")
    for item_price in soup.findAll('span', {'class': 'notranslate'}):
            price = item_price.string
            return price

trade_spider(1)
```

Now i have tried youtube and found a working solution however not for my code. i think this might be because of the modules i am using. So does anyone have a way to execute this code and return the output?

Comment: You dont -- websites are written in Javascript which is the only language that a browser will run. So you either rewrite this in javascript or put the python code on a server and have the website call this code via a ajax request.

Comment: Are you using a web framework? How are you "creating a website"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use python web servers like apache tornado e.g.

but I advice you to search about django to learn better about web development by python.

Comment: i will try this, any tutorial suggestions?

Comment: @fr06t In fact I'm not python developer, but apparently it's well for starting that: https://www.djangoproject.com/start/ , also you can find a lot of articles on YouTube, GoodLuck

Comment: Or Flask which is a more lightweight web framework (for hacks like me :))

Comment: Yea I second Flask. Don't bother with Django.. Flask will work fine for what you want to do